# Does dependent columns matrix reduce the dimension of output vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that matrix having linear dependent columns have zero determinant as they bring vector to lower dimension, but when i checked this fact by multiplying a 3x3 matrix with dependent column with 3x1 vector the output was a vector in 3d. what concept i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a “matrix having linear dependent columns have zero determinant”, but justifying this asserting that “they bring vector to lower dimension” makes no sense. If you see that $3\times3$ matrix as a linear map, then what is true is that the dimension of its range is smaller than $3$. But each vector from $\Bbb R^3$ is still mapped to a vector of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: how can you then justify that determinant is zero because determinant in R^3 would tell what happens to volume after transformation. zero value means either space is collapsed in lower dimension or we are multiplying zero matrix. Latter is not the case as we know.

Comment: The absolute value of the determinant is the volume of the image of a cube with volume $1$. Since that image is, at most, $2$-dimensional, that volume is $0$ and so the determinant can only be $0$.